# std::locale/std::facet Critical section

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, locale

Out of curiosity. In the past I've seen performance degradation in function like `boost::to_lower` because of the `CriticalSection` employed in `std::use_facet` when the lazy facet is allocated. As far as I remember there was a bug with global lock on locale but according to Stephan Lavavej it was fixed in VS2013. And voila, I saw this lock on facet killing server performance yesterday so I guess I'm confusing two different issues.

 But in the first place, why there is a `CriticalSection` around the lazy facet? Obviously it will ruin the performance. Why they didnt resolve to some kind of upgradable lock or atomic operations on pointers?

Comment: I have the same question...

Comment: @Mehrdad, if you really want the answer you better ask the VC++ team or open a ticket on Microsoft Connect

Comment: Could you add a link to where Stephan Lavavej said it was fixed in VS2013?

Comment: 3 years, go find it... I'll try to look for the link

Comment: @Frank, It is nearly impossible to find this issue since Microsoft killed the Connect in favor of Collaborate. Nearest hits are here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b049dbda-c115-410b-b5d8-513f727baf4d/can-stl-streams-run-concurrently-?forum=vcgeneral and here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2012/06/15/stl-bugs-fixed-in-visual-studio-2012/  Connect issue: 492561

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSVC++'s `std::locale` is implemented in terms of the underlying C function `setlocale`. That touches global state, and must therefore be protected by a lock.

Changing the locking semantics of a data structure is unfortunately an ABI breaking change, so not much we'll be able to do about it for a while.

Comment: Hm, have you actually stepped through the code? If I simply run `for (;;) { std::use_facet<std::numpunct<char> >(loc); }` and step through it, I see a lock being acquired and released inside `use_facet` without any apparent interaction with the C-based locale stuff at all. So, unless I'm missing something, I'm not sure this answer is the correct answer to this question...

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you do that facets will be cached so it doesn't need to go into setlocale. But unfortunately the same lock is used to protect the table of cached facets itself
 :/

Comment: Yeah, so I guess the question is... why did they design it this way? Is it just something they've overlooked, or is there more to the story?

Comment: No idea; I guess you'd have to ask Dinkumware. I don't think this stuff has been touched in the last decade :/

Comment: @BillyONeal, I guess you are somewhat closer to Dinkum than we are :)

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg Not really. The dissolution of partnership with Dinkumware for the standard library predates my arrival on the VC++ team :)

Comment: Didnt know you dont work with Dinkumware anymore. Well then roll your own CRT, easy-peasy :)